# Problem configuring virtual host

Tags: windows, apache-2.2

I am tring to configure apache virtual host for my computer. 
But i am facing problem in doing so.

i have made required changes in my C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts 
then C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf 
 I added the following lines in httpd-vhosts.conf

```
########################Virtual Hosts Config below##################

NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1

    <VirtualHost localhost>
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

        <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs">            
            AllowOverride All            
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>


    <VirtualHost virtual.cloudse7en.com>
        ServerName virtual.cloudse7en.com
        DocumentRoot "C:\development\virtual.cloudse7en.com\httpdocs"
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

        <Directory "C:\development\virtual.cloudse7en.com\httpdocs">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost virtual.app.cloudse7en.com>
        ServerName virtual.app.cloudse7en.com
        DocumentRoot "C:\development\virtual.app.cloudse7en.com\httpdocs"
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

        <Directory "C:\development\virtual.app.cloudse7en.com\httpdocs">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>


########################################################################
```

I started my xampp and tried http://localhost in a browser. This works and open up http://localhost/xampp/

but when i try http:http://virtual.app.cloudse7en.com it again opens up http://virtual.app.cloudse7en.com/xampp/

I do not understand the reason. 
Also i have a windows vista 64 bit, operating system. Do i need to make some other changes too?

Regards
Zee

Comment: There is probably something in a .htaccess file inside your document root (C:\development\virtual.app.cloudse7en.com\httpdocs)

Comment: This might be too trivial. But.., Did you make sure to uncomment the include line in httpd.conf for vhosts file?

Answer (score 1):

The part after `<VirtualHost` has to match the part after after `NameVirtualHost` in every case.  (This feature makes it possible to have multiple domains on multiple IP address on one machine.)  In your case:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Jason's answer, Apache uses a HTTP header from the client that has to match the ServerName variable inside a given config block; the config block must match the same IP interface. The most typical way to write what you're doing is this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName default.server.com
  ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName virtual-1.server.com
  ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName virtual-2.server.com
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

If you want to specifically use 127.0.0.1 that's fine, works as well. However, there's a more interesting way to do this that doesn't involve using your hosts file - different ports. It might look like:

```
Listen 80
Listen 81
Listen 82

NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:81
NameVirtualHost *:82

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName default.server.com
  ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:81>
  ServerName virtual-1.server.com
  ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:82>
  ServerName virtual-2.server.com
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Then all you need to do is web browse using different ports:

```
http://localhost:80/
http://localhost:81/
http://localhost:82/
```

...and each one will take you to that config block.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `ServerRoot` in `httpd.cnf`.

Also check this out: http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=29980&start=0&sid=fbb155f1e06ce2c9564702936fe0c931&view=print